# Using .map to write out a domain name and link to the domain name Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Project, that can have multiple Domains. So, on the Index(project) page I'm using the following code to write out the domains with commas separating them

```
<%= project.domains.map { |d| d.name }.join(", ") %>
```

What I would like to do is have the domains be clickable and lead to the respective websites. I need a solution that will add http:// before the domain.name. Like this:

```
"http://" + "d.name"
```

Is this possible? Or is there a better/easier way to do it?
I'm new to Rails and I've been having trouble finding any information on this. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<%= project.domains.map{ |domain| link_to "http://#{domain.name}", "http://#{domain.name}" }.join(', ').html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "reduce" for this. It defines an operator between each 2 elements.

```
project.domains.reduce("") do |result, value| 
    "#{result}http://#{value}, "
end
```